# How could I have a cck field get the computed value of another cck field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, field, drupal-modules, cck

Lets say I have a cck field called foo.  It is a text field with php input.  Say the php code in foo field results in the value of 1,256 when computed.  I need cck field called bar to pick up/obtain/have the VALUE (1,256) of cck field foo.

```
Node XYZ
Foo:*some php code*      ===>results in value of 1,256
Bar:1,256
```

If I just have cck field Foo in a node, it spits out the correct value, (1,256) but that field is the way our views are sorted; and views cant sort by a php field.

I tried to get computed_field.module to obtain its value, but it would spit out the php code, not the value.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Do you mean "foo" obtains that value on submit, or before submit?

Comment: Submit of the node?  If that's what you mean, then on submit.  I need Bar to ONLY have the value of 1256 (integers or text).  I basically need the field to have the integers 1256 stored in the db.  See, field Foo is a computed Alexa Traffic Rank number.  It's php code that returns the number upon compute.  This number can can stay that computed value in the database until It is recomputed. computed_field recomputed the value upon re-saving the node.  (If that gives you more of an idea).

Comment: And also I would be ok if field Bar somehow was able to scrape/extract the value, or just somehow read the value outputted, and not the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook the node submit form, and add a submit handler

```
function moduleNameHere_form_nodeNameHere_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
             //Add handler
             $form['#submit'][] = 'moduleNameHere_submit_function';
}
```

then you create the handler that will get called on submit

```
function moduleNameHere_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
   //Assign foo's value to variable
   $myValue = $form_state['values']['foo'];

   //Set bar to foo's variable
   $form_state['values']['bar'] = $myValue;

}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly when I integrated your code into my module  that retrieves the ranks.  Logically it makes perfect sense.  Thank you very much for your help @cinqoTimo

Comment: On first look, it was working.  I tested it out with 3 nodes in a view.  It was sorting correctly.  I was sorting it by field Bar.  I first did ascending, then descending; all worked fine.  Then when I started adding more nodes, the results were not sorting.  Any ideas?

Comment: If I go into a node edit, field foo is the php code (php filter on), and is also copied into field bar (php filter on). The text displayed inside of field bar is the php code from foo, and not the value of foo.